# How to avoid overtightening flexible water supply hose connectors

Tags: plumbing, hose

Concerning standardised water supply hoses such as the 15mm braided hose below.

[image]

I've come across two schools of thought on how tight the hex nut connectors should be:

1. Hand-tighten *only*.
2. Hand-tighten then apply spanner for **quarter-turn** to **half-turn**.

In the absence of instructions specific to manufacturer/model, what would you advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 2**, with caveat...

These water supply hoses undergo cycles of temperature change and are subjected to vibration due to flow. For me to be confident that the connections won't loosen and leak over time, I always give them a "snug-up" with a wrench. I don't strictly adhere to either a 1/4 turn or 1/2 turn... I hand tighten then give just a bit of a snug, by feel. They will leak if over-tightened.

Comment: Same for me - just need the “magic” in the fingers...

Comment: To someone with no experience fitting flexis, is there any way to describe that limit before you risk overtightening, by feel? Or is it something that really needs practical experience?

Comment: I would say 1/4 turn is a good benchmark. If it doesn't feel snug at that point (or if you use plumber's grease on the nut and gasket like I do) give er a little extra love.